# Why do I have "Removed 582 rows containing missing values (geom_point). "?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I have 5 csv files and I'd like to plot 5 graphs in one plot and in order to do that, I wrote the following code :

```
filenames <- list.files('C:/Users/huonn/Desktop/Thèse recherche/data1', full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.csv$')

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  indice <- read.csv(x)
  names(indice)[names(indice) == "ï..Date"] <- "Date"
  indice$Date <- as.Date(indice$Date, format = "d/%m/%Y")
  indice$Dernier <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", indice$Dernier)))  
  
  ggplot(indice, aes(x = Date, y = Dernier)) +
    geom_point(col="blue")+
    labs(title = "Graphique boursier de l'indice",
         x = "Date", y = "Cours boursier") +
    scale_x_date(limits=c(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2021-04-13")))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10000)) 
})
```

Here's the error that I get :

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 582 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 575 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
3: Removed 574 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
4: Removed 574 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
5: Removed 574 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I don't understand why I get this error and what I see is this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8SmQ.png

No graphs is appearing

Comment: This is because you have missing values for either "Date" or "Dernier". It's hard to tell exactly without reproducible code, but I think it's because you're missing a `%` in your format string when you use `as.Date()`

Comment: It would help if you could share a reproducible example, but I noticed this line "  indice$Date <- as.Date(indice$Date, format = "d/%m/%Y")" is missing a % in front of 'd'

Comment: If adding the `%` in front of the d doesn't work, then try adding a `print(head(indice))` right before your `ggplot` chunk begins. This will print out your data as it is directly before it goes into the plotting function, and should help you debug.

Comment: As the axis have hard limits, and not Cartesian coordinates, is it possible that all the values are outside the range of the axis?  This could caused by the missing "%" with the date conversion.  Comment out the scale_x and scale_y and see if there are points.

Comment: Agree with @TechCommodities on the method of debugging.  Comment out your `scale_x` and `scale_y` lines and see if you get a plot.  If you do, it's an issue with the limits.  If you don't , it's probably an issue with the `as.Date()` or `as.numeric(...` lines.  Check both of those manually for one of your datasets to be sure it's doing what you think it's doing.  If you need more help here, we're going to have to see some sample data shared as `dput(your data)`.